# Javascript d3 reading from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Ok, so I am a bit of a noob with javascript and I need to read data from a csv to make a barchart with d3. The barchart is no problem for me, the reading from the csv file is. This is my code:

```
var dataset;
    d3.csv("gender_ratio.csv", function(data) {
    dataset = data;
    return dataset;
});

var add = function(year, total, males, females){
    var year = {
        year: year,
        total: total,
        males: males,
        females: females
    };
    newdata.push(year);
    return newdata;
};

for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i += 4){
    add(dataset[i], dataset[i+1], dataset[i+2], dataset[i+3]);
    return newdata;
};
```

Can someone tell me what I is going wrong here? I am running this with modzilla firefox, so the browser security isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

The call to load the csv data completes asynchronously. That means your `for` loop is run before the data has been loaded.

If you move the for loop into the callback function of the call to `d3.csv` then the data will be available.

You should also check what the returned data looks like for [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). Your code assumes it is returning a flat array, whereas it actually returns an array of objects where each element represents a row. If you add a `console.log` in the callback of the function you'll get a better sense of what the data looks like.

You also have a `return` statement in that for loop which means it'll only process the first element of data before exiting the loop.

```
d3.csv("gender_ratio.csv", function(data) {
    dataset = data;
    // process data here
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First, d3's `.csv` function works asynchronous, thus you need to call te actual bar chart drawing function within the `.csv` function. If the csv file has a first row featuring column names, you can use a callback function:

```
var dataset = [];
d3.csv("gender_ratio.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    year: d.year,
    total: d.total,
    males: d.males,
    females: d.females,
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  dataset = rows;
  drawBarChart();  /* <<-- This would be the call to the drawing function. */
});
```